# Drupal View adding trailing zeros to Activity ID

Tags: activities, drupal-views

I have a Drupal View displayed as a block, which includes a link to a webform using the Activity ID and the Contact ID for logged in users. It's been working fine but now I find that it's adding trailing zeros onto the aid, e.g. https://my.site/volunteer-role?cid2=540&aid=78668.0000

This is the link in a global custom text field: "volunteer-role?cid2=[contact_id]&aid=[id]"

Any ideas how I can remedy this?

[image]

Comment: can you paste the screenshot of the "activity id" field settings on your drupal view?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it! While getting a screengrab, I noticed there was some aggregation on the Activity Field which I must've set it in error!

[image]

I reset this to the default and it's working.